# Qual o overhead ao utilizar Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony-2, doctrine-2, silex

Há alguns dias estive discutindo com alguns colegas de trabalho a respeito de performance e alta disponibilidade.

No meio da discussão um dos pontos levantados foi que ao atingir um determinado número de requisições, o [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) passa a ser um gargalo na aplicação, e teríamos que usar [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) para manter a performance.

Não consegui aceitar o argumento, uma vez que projetos gigantescos como o PornHub utilizam Symfony com Doctrine e conseguem atender a um número monstruoso de requisições.

Não bastasse existirem projetos que comprovam a eficiencia da biblioteca, existe toda uma questão de sintaxe e produtividade envolvida. Ao utilizar o ORM estamos ganhando muita produtividade, pois evitamos códigos repetitivos e que podem levar a erros.

Dados estes fatos, como podemos medir corretamente a diferença de overhead em utilizar o PDO puro e utilizar o Doctrine ORM?

**Importante**: Apesar da pergunta ser baseada na minha experiência de uso da biblioteca, meu objetivo é técnico, portanto desejo receber respostas que demonstrem tecnicamente a vantagem e desvantagem do uso de cada ferramenta.

Comment: Possivelmente "cache back-end" + "uma série de servidores enxutos".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu não acredito que uma biblioteca tenha apenas pontos negativos, como também não possua apenas pontos positivos.

Quando eu vejo programadores fazendo esse tipo de comentário, eu geralmente costumo ignorar.

As coisas importantes a se perguntar é: Qual é a sua experiência para dizer isso?

Mostrar somente os pontos negativos de algo é ser incoerente e parcial.

Eu também diria que existe em alguns uma eterna guerra de quem não usa frameworks ou bibliotecas querendo converser quem usa a parar de usar, ou vice-versa.

## O Doctrine

No meu ponto de vista, o Doctrine é um framework para banco de dados bastante robusto e que vista, como dito na pergunta, evitar a repetição de código.

Além do mais ele conta com um modelo relacional, que é necessário muitas vezes para melhor organização do acesso/registro dos dados do banco de dados na sua aplicação - coisa que não existe usando `PDO` puro.

## E a performance?

Sobre a questão da performance, eu tenho que dizer: *De alguma forma você terá que pagar pela sua escolha*.

Se você escolher preocupar tanto com a performance ao ponto de deixar de usar o Doctrine, terá que fazer muita coisa na mão, ou então optar por uma outra biblioteca, mas aí você teria que avaliar se as trocas compensam o tempo gasto.

Por outro lado ao optar por usar somente o `PDO`, você estaria gastando muito tempo refazendo queries manualmente.

Então, pese as duas coisas na balança e decida em qual lado você vai ficar.

Eu parei a muito tempo de me preocupar com microotimizações.

Eu acho que as coisas devem ser pesadas na balança. É fácil dizer que um caminhão é grande demais para caber numa garagem, mas se esquecer que ele pode carregar uma toneladas de coisas.

O que quero dizer é que você tem que avaliar se seu projeto de fato se beneficiará com uso de uma biblioteca X ou Y.

Um jargão que vejo entre os programadores, no qual eu concordo, é : *Por que usar uma bazuka pra matar uma formiga?*.

Eu não acho que faria sentido usar o Doctrine para fazer um sitezinho simples, que possui apenas três tabelas para consulta. Mas se for fazer algo mais robusto/escalável, recomendaria altamente utilizá-lo.

## Conclusão

Alguns programadores podem dar opiniões dizendo que pode gerar Overhead, mas isso foi baseado em quê?

Qual é o tamanho da aplicação que eles já desenvolveram? Qual é o cenário?

Com o perdão da piada, mas **qualquer biblioteca que você use usará mais memória/recursos na sua aplicação do que se você não usasse**. Mas no final das contas, sem elas, você teria uma penca de coisas pra ficar escrevendo para a sua aplicação.

Outro detalhe: Alguns costuma tachar algo como ruim, porque fizeram mal uso da ferramenta e, ao invés de admitir que errou, culpam o framework (eu mesmo já caí nesse erro :) ).

Além do mais, Doctrine é um framework (para não dizer o único) dos mais robustos que conheço para banco de dados em PHP.

Outro detalhe é que se você achar que não compensa usar o ORM do Doctrine, ainda poderá usar outros recursos, como o Doctrine Query Builder, que é um construtor de queries do Doctrine que também poderá ajudar a evitar a repetição de código.